# Automatically export a OneNote section to PDF

Tags: windows, powershell, onenote

I have a `.one` OneNote section file that I would like to automatically export to PDF at regular intervals. In Powershell 7, I discovered this command:

```
Start-Process "C:\path\to\ONENOTE.EXE" -ArgumentList "/print `"C:\path\to\my_section.one`""
```

This opens OneNote and the save location dialog for the PDF, but I can't figure out how to provide input to this dialog at the command line. I'm not sure if there's an appropriate module - I looked at https://www.powershellgallery.com/ and couldn't find one. Any ideas on how to extend the above command, or another solution entirely?

Comment: PS is not really meant/designed to be a GUI control tool. Though you can with some gymnastics. You are calling an ```*.exe``` from PS, and that is a thing, but that does not me PS controls the ```*.exe```. You must provide all that ```*.exe``` requires/allows to get what you want.  As noted, you can use SendKeys directly in PS, without any reliance on the VBS that '@KJ" hints at. This means capturing the focus on that dialog to send keys to make it do stuff.

Comment: There is a cmdlets module for OneNote in Microsoft tpowershellgallery.com. Just search for it. ```Find-Module -Name '*OneNote*' |  Format-List -Force``` You need to mess with it to see if it can provide what you are after. I've had no reason to use it personally. Lastly, like almost all MSOffice products, you can use COM to execute automation needs. ['powershell OneNote COM'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+OneNote+COM%27&t=h_&ia=web) You could also, directly just set your default printer to the Windows PDF one, using PS, and just print as normal, skipping calling the ```*.exe``` call.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment. Your use case could be as simple as this:

```
$CurrentDefaultPrinter = (
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Printer | 
Where-Object {$PSItem.Default -eq $true}
).Name

$CurrentDefaultPrinter 

Get-Printer | 
Where-Object {$PSItem.Name -Match 'pdf'} | 
Set-Printer -Name $PSItem.Name
Start-Process 'C:\path\to\ONENOTE.EXE' -FilePath 'C:\path\to\my_section.one' -Verb Print

Set-Printer -Name $CUrrentDefaultPrinter
```